# Creating Three.js meshes in a WebWorker

Tags: multithreading, three.js, web-worker

I'm trying to offload as many Threejs computations as possible to a Web Worker. It seems to be relatively doable when just wanting the worker to create geometries. However, I still need to create a significant amount of meshes, which implies a hefty cycle on the main thread.

Is it possible to offload mesh creation to a web worker and just have the main thread add it to the scene (when ready)?

The idea would be to have the worker create an array of meshes, based on some data, and have it send it over to the main thread.

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I dont see real reason. Question is very interest but why you what web worker ? Maybe performance ...

Answer (score 3):

I am currently willing to tackle this problem in one of my projects. If you haven't started yet yours, I would suggest to have a look at https://github.com/kripken/webgl-worker first. There are two examples (one simple, one a bit more complex) that could help to start with.

I will update later this answer with more details about how to integrate wegl-worker with three.js, which might require more setup than simple webgl/worker implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, THREEJS 3D objects (classes) are to "heavy" to be used in workers (object can't pass through "worker thread"-"main thread" boundary, even after I patched threejs lib to be used inside worker).

But I successfully use workers to load pretty large objects asynchronously.
I use Catiline.js for convenience.

The idea is to use THREEJS objects native format (and buffer geometry) and simply parse it to js object inside worker. After it, you can use THREE.ObjectLoader in the main thread to get real scene object. The benefit from such approach is to move parsing (which can take quite a long time for the large object) to background and minify freezing.

I use 6 workers, choose worker randomly, pass data url to it and additionaly get benefits from XMLHttpRequest caching

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of your approach?

Answer (score 1):

Threejs objects can't be passed through a postMessage.

Instead we want to set up a connection back to the main page via web-sockets. This should let us freely pass whatever is needed.

Comment: You can pass fully formed js objects with function refs through WebSockets?

Answer (score 1):

This thread might be helpful to you... I recently had to do some SSR with Three.js and the concepts are similar expect you are parsing Buffer Geometries with ObjectLoader in the worker.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/error-with-ssr-three-js-objects/8643